# What is the “something greater than Solomon” in Matthew 12?

Tags: pneumatology, solomon, matthew

To whom or what is Jesus referring in this passage when he speaks of “something greater than Solomon”?

> The queen of the South will rise up at the judgment with this
> generation and condemn it, for she came from the ends of the earth to
> hear the wisdom of Solomon, and behold, something greater than Solomon
> is here. (Matthew 12:42, ESV)

I have always assumed it was Jesus, but much of Matthew 12 is about the Holy Spirit. Solomon was a wise counselor and the Holy Spirit is the Counselor that Jesus would send. Do any theologians hold that Jesus is speaking of the Holy Spirit and not himself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The text does not specify 'something' or 'someone'. Thus Jesus' words do not *state* either meaning.

> πλειον σολομωντος ωδε  [Matthew 12:42b TR (undisputed)]

This means 'greater than Solomon here' ([see Biblehub Interlinear](https://biblehub.com/interlinear/matthew/12-42.htm)) or see Bagster's Greek New Testament, interlinear translation 'more than Solomon here'.

In English we need to supply a verb 'is' but it is interpretation (rather than faithful translation) to force more meaning upon Jesus' words.

The KJV states 'a greater' and thus does not insist on 'something' or 'someone' and I would suggest that that is a correct and restrained translation, avoiding added meaning, by making a noun out of an adjective, by adding the article.

Jesus is, I would suggest, implying something without saying it.

Yes, someone greater than Solomon was present but Jesus has not (exactly) stated that. It is similar to many other words of Jesus of Nazareth who did not seek glory for himself, but rather sought the glory of His Father in heaven.

I am not aware of any authoritative exponent of the interpretation you mention in your last sentence.

Answer (score 1):

It is Jesus Himself. In both cases. He is greater than Jonah and Solomon.

Jesus' words of Matthew 12:42 are alluding to the prophecy given to king David in 2 Samuel 7. Solomon was a son of David, but Jesus is the son of David who is also the son of God. Solomon was a king of Israel, but Jesus is the king of Israel forever.  Solomon built for God a temple, a mere building. Jesus built the true temple, the one that God always desired and wanted, unlike the one made by David and Solomon.